# Five points on a constant-width curve

Tags: geometry, euclidean-geometry, plane-geometry, plane-curves, combinatorial-geometry

Is there a [curve of constant width](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Curve_of_constant_width) $1$ on which it is impossible to arrange the five points $A, B, C, D, E$ so that $\max(AB, BC, CD, DE, EA) \leqslant \sin (\frac{\pi}{5})$?

For example, on a circle, you can place the points in the form of a regular pentagon, and the distance will be exactly $\sin (\frac{\pi}{5})$.

Does anyone have any idea how to place such points on an arbitrary curve of width $1$?

And more general hypothesis: for any $n$ on any curve of constant width $1$, we can place $n$ points $A_1, A_2, ..., A_n, A_{n+1}=A_1$, such that $\max_{i=1..n} (A_{i}A_{i+1}) \leqslant \sin (\frac{\pi}{n})$.

Upd: this is true for $n \leqslant 4$. $n=1$ and $n=2$ is trivial cases. For $n = 3$, we can put the curve in [a universal Pal's cover](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lebesgue%27s_universal_covering_problem) and then divide it into three parts of diameter $\sin(\frac{\pi}{3})$. For $n=4$, we can put the curve in a square with side $1$, and divide it into four small squares of diameter $\sin(\frac{\pi}{4})$.

Comment: This is trivial: one can place $A = B = C = D = E$ so that $\max(AB, BC, CD, DE, EA) = 0 \le \sin \frac{\pi}{5}$. Are you missing some condition?

Comment: @AndersKaseorg I think the condition that I had in mind intuitively was something like “there is no width (segment between two points of tangency to parallel lines) such that all points lie on one side of it”; equivalently, no point can be moved by epsilon along the curve without increasing one of the distances to the other points. Also equivalently, the maximum distance should be at a local minimum other than $0$. Less formally, the points should go “around the curve” in some sense.

Comment: Yes, these points should in some sense form something close to a regular pentagon